# Integrate Ruby application with my Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scripting, integration

I have an application in Ruby that gets information from some hosts and saves it in a file. Every time it gets the information (every 15 minutes), a new file is generated. Now, I want to create a Rails app, with a database to configure the application (ip of the host, passwords etc) and to save the data from hosts.

I've already created a database using rails, I need to integrate my program within the rails app. Where should I place the script and who gets the information into the database inside the rails structure? I need this script running together with the rails app, I mean, when I run the rails app the script should start. At the same time, from the script I need to use the Database tools that Active Directory gives to me to manage the DB using the ORM.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has ActiveJobs which you could use to regularly communicate with the other service.

Using the built-in rails generator you can create your job and it includes a stubbed test for ensuring you're script functions the way you expect.

```
bin/rails generate job guests_cleanup
#=> invoke  test_unit
#=> create    test/jobs/guests_cleanup_job_test.rb
#=> create  app/jobs/guests_cleanup_job.rb
```

In the job you can then communicate with your Ruby application on a regular schedule.

```
class GuestsCleanupJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*guests)
    # Do something later
  end
end
```

To schedule this job to regularly execute, use one of the following gems.

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling

Comment: Ok, gonna look some information about that. But, I need to know, where should I place my script and use Active Records from the Rails App?

Comment: I'll post an example.

Comment: Ok, then every time I run "rails server" is it going to be executed?

Comment: It will run once by default, so you will need to reschedule it.

Comment: There are gems for scheduling jobs; I've used whenever, but the Rufus-scheduler is also popular.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a cron job in rails that runs the script in every 15 minute.
At your cron configuration file it would look something like:

```
*/15 * * * * ruby your_ruby_script.rb
```

In that script you can manipulate your database as per your requirement.